# Game Play / Pause Toggle Setup

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a problem with setting up toggle with my available graphics.
Basically Unity has created this in the wrong way.

This is happening to me:
Off State Toggle
[image]

On State Toggle

[image]

Now as you have seen, in the above image, On state is not displaying properly.
I have displayed both state graphics in the above both images.
Unity's default Toggle working like this way so how to set up game play/pause toggle?

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create a Game Object reference in your `Script` for Play Image and One for Pause Image.
Initially set Play Image to Disabled.
 Then When ever Button is pressed to Pause the Game, Disable Pause Image using `<Pause Image Gameobject Variable Name>.SetActive(false)` and Enable the Play Button using `<Pause Image Gameobject Variable Name>.SetActive(true)`. Also You can Do the Same when the Button is pressed Again.
**Ask in reply for a Example Script.**

Comment: Regarding this manual process I understand, any kind of Unity in-built mechanism exists that I don't know - that reason I have posted this question. This is major thing that is missing in Unity UI elements.

Comment: As much I know, There is no other Mechanism